# Is there a way to pause and continue iCloud Photo syncing from command line?

Tags: icloud, photos

Uploading about 600GB of photos to iCloud Photos over a 300KB uplink takes weeks but also creates network congestion that destroys any download bandwidth. The only obvious way to control it is to navigate to the Photos Preferences window and hit the Pause or Continue button. Is there any way to do this from the command line? Any launchctl commands that might work?

Comment: The command line would do the same so what is the point?

Answer (score 0):

via reddit I found a shell script on Github that does this. It runs constantly, and you have to start it via the terminal

https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/bi4yuc/is_there_seriously_no_way_to_pause_icloud_syncing/

Seems to work! It's really useful if you've gone over the limit on your data allocation for cellular but haven't a fully synced library and are trying to use the computer till month data rollover period.

As it's running constantly, it might use extra battery but I doubt it -  however that's something I haven't tested.

Github for the script is here.

https://github.com/farnots/StopNsurlsessiond

Even though it's 6 or so years old, it still works on Big Sur v11.7.6

Tripmode.ch also is said to work, and is far easier and user friendly (I tried the trial) -

The script above is easier for a /coder/programmer/technical person/time-rich person/experienced person/ etc. to use

How I ran it?
After downloading, I went into the Downloads folder in Finder, then double clicked on the zip file, to expand it into a folder.

I used the launchpad.
I typed Terminal, then clicked it when I found it in launchpad
Then I typed

```
ls
```

From the list of directories and files, I could see I was in the user home directory. I could see the Downloads folder there.
So I typed

```
cd Downloads
```

then I typed

```
ls
```

I could see the folder it expanded to, so I typed

```
cd StopNsurlsessiond-master
```

then I typed

```
ls
```

to see what was in the folder. I could see the script file there, so I typed

```
chmod u+x ./StopNsurl.sh
```

That seemed to work, because it didn't respond with an error message.

So I then typed

```
./StopNsurl.sh -v
```

And it ran.

This is the output of the software.

```
+----------------------------------------+
| Starting annihilation of nsurlsessiond |
|        Made by Lucas Tarasconi         |
+----------------------------------------+
[WARNING] Password could be asked once to have the right to kill 'nsurlsessiond' 
[INFO] Probing for new nsurlsessiond process  
Password:
[PROCESS] 07:48:47 - killing nsurlsessiond number :  212
[PROCESS] 07:48:47 - killing nsurlsessiond number :  442
[INFO] Probing for new nsurlsessiond process      
[PROCESS] 07:50:58 - killing nsurlsessiond number :  3054
[PROCESS] 07:50:58 - killing nsurlsessiond number :  3055
[INFO] Probing for new nsurlsessiond process      
[PROCESS] 07:51:08 - killing nsurlsessiond number :  3237
[PROCESS] 07:51:08 - killing nsurlsessiond number :  3238
[INFO] Probing for new nsurlsessiond process      
[PROCESS] 07:51:19 - killing nsurlsessiond number :  3427
[PROCESS] 07:51:19 - killing nsurlsessiond number :  3428
[INFO] Probing for new nsurlsessiond process      
[PROCESS] 07:51:30 - killing nsurlsessiond number :  3616
[PROCESS] 07:51:30 - killing nsurlsessiond number :  3622
[INFO] Probing for new nsurlsessiond process      
[PROCESS] 07:51:41 - killing nsurlsessiond number :  3801
[PROCESS] 07:51:41 - killing nsurlsessiond number :  3802
[INFO] Probing for new nsurlsessiond process      
[PROCESS] 07:51:51 - killing nsurlsessiond number :  3984
[INFO] Probing for new nsurlsessiond process      
[PROCESS] 07:51:52 - killing nsurlsessiond number :  4009
[INFO] Probing for new nsurlsessiond process      
[PROCESS] 07:52:02 - killing nsurlsessiond number :  4173
[INFO] Probing for new nsurlsessiond process      
[PROCESS] 07:52:03 - killing nsurlsessiond number :  4208
```